# Cannot find controller (following PR2/Gazebo/Quick Start recipe)

Tags: gazebo, moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using this recipe (with Indigo) from
http://moveit.ros.org/wiki/PR2/Gazebo/Quick_Start
I try to get my (crustcrawler/dynamixel) arm working in gazebo.
For my complete config see  http://fwn06.housing.rug.nl/ros/my_movit.

I start gazebo and then  "roslaunch my_movit smart_arm_moveit_planning_execution.launch"

During the start I get the following error:

```
       ........
[ INFO] [1427716093.344226043, 51.360000000]: MoveitSimpleControllerManager: Waiting for arm_controller/follow_joint_trajectory to come up
[ INFO] [1427716096.761115168, 54.769000000]: Loading robot model 'smart_arm'...
[ INFO] [1427716096.761200375, 54.769000000]: No root joint specified. Assuming fixed joint
[ERROR] [1427716098.358135532, 56.360000000]: MoveitSimpleControllerManager: Action client not connected: arm_controller/follow_joint_trajectory
    .......
```

My controller.yaml is

```
controller_manager_ns: smart_arm_controller_manager
controller_list:
 - name: arm_controller
   action_ns: follow_joint_trajectory
   type: FollowJointTrajectory
   default: true
   joints:
      [ shoulder_pan_joint, shoulder_pitch_joint, elbow_flex_joint,  wrist_roll_joint ]
```

The setting of name and action_ns is a bit of a guess, and I think that the question is how to connect this to the description in my smart_arm.urdf.
Does it has to do with the value of robotSimType in the gazebo-plugin setting?

Can anybody give me a pointer?
Thanks in advance, Sietse

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206245/cannot-find-controller-(following-pr2/gazebo/quick-start-recipe)/) by [Sietse](https://answers.ros.org/users/15266/sietse/) on ROS Answers with karma: 168 on 2015-03-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is a working example from my robot. This is the arm section of the robot's ctrlr_params.yaml file:

```
arm_ctrlr:
  type: position_controllers/JointTrajectoryController
  joints:
    - arm_base_joint
    - shoulder_joint
    - elbow_joint
    - wrist_roll_joint
    - wrist_pitch_joint
    - wrist_yaw_joint
  stop_trajectory_duration: 0.1
  state_publish_rate: 1.0
```

Here is the transmission definition for arm_base_joint from the robot's URDF file:

```
  <transmission name="arm_base_trans">
    <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
    <joint name="arm_base_joint">
      <hardwareInterface>PositionJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    </joint>
    <actuator name="arm_base_act">
      <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
    </actuator>
  </transmission>
```

---

Originally posted by [Jim Rothrock](https://answers.ros.org/users/274/jim-rothrock/) with karma: 792 on 2015-03-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sietse](https://answers.ros.org/users/15266/sietse/) on 2015-04-02**:
Thanks for the answer. I now am a little bit further.
I will refrase my problem in a new question.